# SQL Join 3 tables with conditions (Max value)

Tags: sql

I have a question about joining 3 tables with some conditions.

I have 3 tables country, region, city. All I want is to return the largest city by population of every country and exclude the cities with 100.000 population or less. The thing is every table is connected with an id that is passed to the next table. Let me elaborate:

Country Table:

| id | iso_code | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | IN | India |
| 2 | US | United States |

Region Table:

| id | country_id | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | Delhi |
| 4 | 1 | Manipur |
| 5 | 2 | Nevada |

City Table:

| id | region_id | name | population |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 3 | New Delhi | 320.000 |
| 7 | 3 | Delhi | 10.000.000 |
| 8 | 4 | Imphal | 220.000 |
| 9 | 5 | Las Vegas | 624.000 |

The output should look like this:

| Country | City |
| --- | --- |
| India | Delhi |
| United States | Las Vegas |

I have done so much research but I can't seem to find a solution.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: 'exclude the cities with 1.000.000 population or less.' - so why is las vegas in your output?

Comment: I removed the conflicting tags; please tag the RDBMS you are *actually* using.

Comment: You are right I meant 100.000 thank you for noticing @P.Salmon

Comment: A case for `row_number()`

Comment: 'I meant 100.000' in thet case new delhi and  imphal should appear?

Comment: @P.Salmon No, because we only want the largest city of every country

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Join them from the foreign keys to the primary keys.
Add a ranking based on country and population.
Wrap it in a sub-query.
Then filter on it.

```
SELECT Country, City
FROM
(
    SELECT
      ctry.name AS Country
    , ctry.iso_code AS CountryCode
    , reg.name AS Region
    , city.name AS City
    , city.population AS CityPopulation
    , DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ctry.id ORDER BY city.population DESC) AS Rnk
    FROM Country AS ctry
    JOIN Region AS reg ON reg.country_id = ctry.id
    JOIN City AS city ON city.region_id = reg.id
) q
WHERE Rnk = 1
  AND CityPopulation > 100000
ORDER BY CityPopulation DESC, Country, City
```

Note that I used DENSE_RANK instead of ROW_NUMBER.
The difference is that a DENSE_RANK would assign the same number to cities within a country with the same population. But a ROW_NUMBER wouldn't.
This way, if 2 cities are both the top in their country, they both get Rnk 1.

If you don't want that a country could potentially have more than 1 top country.  Then use ROW_NUMBER instead, but with a tie-breaker.

F.e.

```
, ROW_NUMBER() 
        OVER (PARTITION BY ctry.id 
              ORDER BY city.population DESC, 
                       LEN(city.name) DESC) AS Rnk
```

Comment: and "All I want is to return the largest city by population of every country" ? Oh wait, they are returned right now... 

Comment: Ah right, largest. Wait a moment.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer but my actual table is a lot bigger and I don't think the "WHERE city.population > 500000" would help because I need the MAX() function

Comment: Changed it. Assuming your database is modern enough to have window functions like DENSE_RANK or ROW_NUMBER.